# Text only ads like UrbanSpoon

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

I am trying to implement text only ads onto my site similar to what UrbanSpoon has here:

[image: see screen shot].

For some reason, when looking through Google DFP and Google AdSense I can only find the ad code that makes my text link ads:

[image: look like this].

There are a stack of sites display text only ads in a similar way to UrbanSpoon. Does anyone know what these ads are called?

Comment: Well, you can try by looking at the webpage's source code for those ads.

Comment: Please could you provide a URL to a page on UrbanSpoon where we can see these ads as I couldn't find them anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When websites receive over a certain volume of traffic/clicks/impressions, AdSense enables them to use more integrated looking, customised ad styles beyond those still pretty generic looking styles.

Unless your traffic is above this threshold, you'll have to make do with the customisations you're  allowed as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend my answer once I've seen the UrbanSpoon page containing these ads but you may want to explore the [custom styles for Adsense ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1669193?hl=en) that is available to all advertisers.

[image]
[image]